# Create Google chart from dynamic number of sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Is there a way to create a chart based on an ever-growing folder of sheets?

For instance, if I want to graph the running average of some value always found in cell A1 across all sheets within a certain folder or from date x to date y or with the same file name prefix of "ABCDE", is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: It's possible with a script that accesses a bunch of files in the folder and gathers data in one place, to plot there. But it's unclear whan the X-axis would be (what's the order of the spreadsheets?), and the whole thing seems hardly worth the effort. Better to invest the time into a saner data storage model.

Answer (score 1):

You can by using the ImportRange() function, and then reference the first cell. You will just need to reference every sheet that you need the information from.

Example:

```
Column A                  Column B     Column C

unique Spreadsheet key    A1           =importRange(A1,b1)
unique Spreadsheet key    A1           =importRange(A1,b1)
```

You will also need permissions from every sheet that you want to import from.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en

It might be better to look at another way to output the data, maybe look to save it in a database.